# Mono Runtime - Can it be forced to ONLY run strong named or signed assemblies?

Tags: c#, mono, strongname

Is there some incantation of Mono Runtime configurations that can be used to force Mono to only run strong named or signed assemblies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

Long answer:

Mono is open source and, in that spirit, there's nothing to limit people to run or modify the runtime or the class libraries that ship with Mono.

Most of the features (e.g. strongnames and even authenticode) exists inside Mono because they can be used for other purposes or, optionally, to sign/verify code.

OTOH that same freedom allows **you** to modify your own mono runtime, sign your assemblies (with your own key) and **require** any assembly to be signed before executing them.

However that was never a requirement for any project I know about (e.g. Moonlight used CoreCLR which did not enforce code signing). That only means it will be something you'll need to figure out, not that's it's impossible: all the pieces are there but, be warned, a fair amount of glue is needed.